# While Loop - String Index out of Range?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm running a `while` loop in Python with this syntax:

```
while not endFound:
    if file[fileIndex] == ';':
        current = current + ';'
        contents.append(current)
        if fileIndex == lengthOfFile:
            endFound = True
    else:
        current = current + file[fileIndex]
    fileIndex = fileIndex + 1
```

And am getting this error in my console:

```
var(vari) = 0;terminal.write(vari);var(contents) = file.getContents('source.py');if(vari : 0) {    terminal.write('vari equals 0');}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/source.py", line 30, in <module>
    splitFile(content)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/source.py", line 22, in splitFile
    if file[fileIndex] == ';':
IndexError: string index out of range

> Process exited with code: 1
```

What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have something like this before you begin:

```
file = "section_1;section_2;section_3;"
lengthOfFile = len(file)
contents = []
current = ""
fileIndex = 0
endFound = False
```

The code you wrote could be slightly clarified as follows:

```
while not endFound:
    next_char = file[fileIndex]
    current = current + next_char
    if next_char == ';':
        contents.append(current)
        #? current = ''
        if fileIndex == lengthOfFile:
            endFound = True
    fileIndex = fileIndex + 1
```

The problem in this particular case is that when you reach the final `;` in `file`, `fileIndex` is 17, but `lengthOfFile` is 18. So the `fileIndex == lengthOfFile` test fails. You could fix the code above by changing this line to `fileIndex + 1 == lengthOfFile`, or by moving the increment operation above `if next_char == ';'`.

But there are simpler ways to write this code in Python. In particular, if your goal is for `contents` to become a list of all the "section_n;" entries in `file`, you could just use something like this:

```
contents = [part + ';' for part in file[:-1].split(';')]
```

(The `[:-1]` omits the last character (`;`) from `file` before splitting it.) Note that if this is what you want, then your original code would also need to reset the value of `current` during each pass, as noted above.

If you actually want `contents` to become a list of longer and longer substrings from the start of `file`, as currently written, you could do something like this:

```
contents1 = file[:-1].split(';')
contents = []
for part in contents1:
    current = current + part + ';'
    contents.append(current)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. What is the value of `fileIndex` before you enter the loop?
2. Check of the end of the string (`if fileIndex == lengthOfFile:`) is inside of `if file[fileIndex] == ';':`, so if there's no `;` in the string, you effectively have infinite loop.
3. Manipulations with characters are not very pythonic, there are most probably more effective tools to do what you (like `.index` method of `str` and so on.)

Comment: Actually, tested it out, no, it didn't. :(

Comment: 1. The value of `fileIndex` starts as 0 and increases until it equals the length ot the file. (This script is being used to split lines in codes for me to read easier, so the semi-colons signify the end of the line.) Is that the problem? An infinite loop? the string is this: `"var(vari) = 0;
terminal.write(vari);
var(contents) = file.getContents('source.py');
if(vari : 0) {
    terminal.write('vari equals 0');
};"` There is an ending semi-colon though.